# OpenLdap. Setting a database as a branch of another database

Tags: openldap

I'm using OpenLdap 2.4.44. I have a mdb database with three different 'branches' dev, tst, pre as folllows:

```
 dc=mytest,dc=com
    dc=dev
       ou=
    dc=tst
       ou=users
    dc=pre
       ou=users
```

and that works fine. But now I want to add a new 'branch', which is actually a meta connection to the production Active Directory. So the final structure should be something like this:

```
 dc=mytest,dc=com
    dc=dev
       ou=
    dc=tst
       ou=users
    dc=pre
       ou=users
    dc=prd
       ou=prd_users
```

The original database has a

```
suffix          "dc=mytest,dc=com"
```

and when I try to add the meta

```
database    meta
suffix         "dc=prd,dc=mytest,dc=com"
```

I get an error saying

```
namingContext "dc=bsi,dc=dev,dc=local" already served by a preceding mdb database serving namingContext "dc=dev,dc=
```

How can I setup the AD meta connection as a branch of the existing database?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some research I found that I can use a database with a suffix that is part of the suffix of another database if I declare the most detailed sufixed database fist. So in this case I just need to declare the database with sufix "dc=prd,dc=mytest,dc=com" before the one with suffix "dc=mytest,dc=com"

This solves the issue.